# Detecting scrolling up is not working Well

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to use this code to get scrolling direction the problem is when scroll up the detection is not going well

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll scroll mousewheel', function(event) {

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
          console.log('scroll up');
        }else {
          console.log('scroll down');
    });

});
```

Here's a screen capture of the result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4gPX.png) it shows scroll up then scroll down but i'm not scrolling down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have way too many events bound.

Try this code, the only difference is that I use it on a div.

```
$('div').bind('mousewheel', function(event) {

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
          console.log('scroll up');
        }else {
          console.log('scroll down');
    }

});
```

Here is a working JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r1sjv2tv/

**Edit:** The above answer works, albeit only when using wheel scroll.
However, the window can also be scrolled with mouse. If you to handle it as well, it will get a bit more complex.

I have made a solution that listens to onscroll event and simply compares the current scrolltop position with the last scrolltop position to determine the direction of a scroll.

```
$('div').bind('scroll', function(event) {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() < $(this).data('last-scroll')) {
    console.log('scroll up');
  } else {
    console.log('scroll down');
  }

  $(this).data('last-scroll',$(this).scrollTop());
});
```

This works independent of the original event trigger.

Please see the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r1sjv2tv/2/

Comment: can i used window instead of div?

Comment: definitely, just replace the 'div'